# How to find out manual entry option button has been clicked in card.io scanner?

Tags: card.io

How to find out manual entry option button has been clicked in card.io scanner?

Is it possible to find out the manual entry button event raised or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

No, it is not possible for you to determine this.

If you wish to change the behavior of the Manual Entry button, then what you really want to do may be to use a CardIOView rather than a CardIOPaymentViewController.

Comment: One further observation: you *can* determine whether the card number was scanned or entered manually *after* the fact. The `CardIOCreditCardInfo` object returned to your delegate includes the property `scanned`.